# Global Variable Issue when Manually Mapping a PE+ Header

Tags: c++, portable-executable

Currently making a manual PE+ mapper and have run into an issue and am honestly completely stuck on. After a few days of work I finally have a "functioning" dll which will inject properly into the target process and can execute imports, however the dll would fail to run any seemingly complex tasks I wrote and I eventually found out why. Basically all of my dynamic global variables were not being initialized at all. In the example below it shows how with a dynamic global variable the output is not correct at all, in this case being "Screen Size > 0 : 0"

Example Code;

```
int screenX = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
int screenY = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if (ul_reason_for_call == 1)
    {
        Beep(500, 500); //Working Perfectly Fine
        std::cout << "Screen Size > " << screenX << " : " << screenY << "\n"; //Prints 0's
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Basically any variables outside of normal execution that are also dynamic on startup just fail to work completely. The only thing I could find for this was the start address being incorrect but I am passing the one given by the header before its removed. Honestly even just a point in the correct direction such as what even initializes these in the first place would be great. Any help much appreciated.